# Strange Timing with STM32F401 ADC

Tags: stm32, adc

I'm observing a strange timing behavior with the ADC of an STM32F401 dev board (Black Pill). I have pin A0 connected to a 10k potentiometer via a 10M resistor (I know the impedance is high, I wanted to test exactly that effect, started out with no resistor at all). I trigger the ADC via a timer running at 10kHz at the beginning of each cycle, measuring A0 and A1 in turn. A1 is tied to ground. My oscilloscope shows the following: (Channel 1 is a 50% duty cycle PWM signal generated from the same timer, channel 2 is connected to the ADC input):

[image: Scope Overview]

Zooming in, with a sample time of 3 cycles.

[image]

The ADC measures about 3100, which matches the 2.5 V measured: 2.5V/3.3V*4096=3103

Now comes the strange part: If I change the sample time to 56 cycles, I get the following:

[image]

The ADC reading stays the same (about 3100) and the voltage drop on the pin moves to later in the timer cycle by about 5us. The SMPR2 register shows the value 0x0000001B, which seems correct.

**Strange thing A:** The ADC clock is set to "PCLK2 divided by 4", and the clock configuration shows 84MHz for PCLK2 (configured via STM32CubeMX). Thus the ADC should run at 21MHz. I changed the sampling time by 53 cycles (56-3), which is 53/21=2.52us. This is half of the observed change of 5us, which would indicate a clock of 10.5MHz.

**Strange thing B:** The timing of the voltage drop changed. I thought the drop would occur at the beginning of the sampling time, and the sampling would just last for longer when the sampling time changes.

**Strange thing C:** The ADC reading stayed about the same (it's a bit noisy, between 3090 and 3110). I have expected a lower reading with 3 cycles (2V/3.3V*4096=2482), and a higher reading with 56 cycles, because the capacitor can charge higher. Changing to 480 cycles sampling time does not change the reading either.

Does anybody have an idea what's going on?

Comment: What is  scope Channel 2 measuring?

Comment: Channel 2 is measuring the input pin of the ADC. Updated the question.